# The "PHPSESSID" cookie was rejected due to an incorrect domain

Tags: php, api, rest, cookies, session-cookies

I'm sending a cookie from an API (written on PHP) which should be received by a client when I log in.

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID', session_id(), time() + (86400 * 30), '/', domain.herokuapp.com, 'secure=true', 'httponly=false');
```

However, I get the following error:
**"The "PHPSESSID" cookie was rejected due to an incorrect domain."**
But if I  change the domain to the API domain (like I change the domain.herokuapp.com to $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), I don't get this error. What should I do? Both of my applications are served on https so the cookies must work.

Comment: Perhaps you simply forgot to put quotes around the domain?

Comment: Does your API live on `domain.herokuapp.com` ?

Comment: Maybe I just don’t have enough coffee, but why are you passing strings to the Boolean parameters? This seems like partial option mode, but without the array?

Comment: @ChrisHaas no, it's the domain-api.herokuapp.com. So they both are served on heroku

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i forgot to put quotes, sorry

Comment: You can’t set a cookie on a domain that doesn’t match the request origin. You could try the shared parent domain, however if it is literally what you posted, that is on the [PSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com), so it wouldn’t work.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Everything works in the Postman, but in browser it doesn't. Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: I have a better question, if I understand it correctly I need to make my API domain the subdomain of the client domain so I can read cookies. But how do I do this?

Comment: Setting a domain is generally just a hosting thing. I’ve never worked with Heroku, so I’m not sure what needs to be done. But you need your client to create a DNS entry, point it to the server, and have the server support it, including TLS.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sounds hard for me but I'll try